# AND WHERE syntax

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This statement is used in my app

```
$result = query("SELECT p.IdPhoto, p.device_token, p.IdUser FROM photos p JOIN login l ON (l.IdUser = p.IdUser) WHERE p.IdPhoto='%d'", $IdPhoto);
```

I'd like to also store the `device_token` value so I added this line.

```
$result = query("SELECT p.IdPhoto, p.device_token, p.IdUser FROM photos p JOIN login l ON (l.IdUser = p.IdUser) WHERE p.IdPhoto='%d' AND p.device_token='%d' ", $IdPhoto, $token);
```

I am running this line of code from an app and it exits when this line is called which is weird because the first line works any idea on how to store the device_token value in a variable as well as IdPhoto?

**php_error.log**

```
[05-Apr-2016 06:21:19 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  Missing argument 2 for stream(), called in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Hi2/index.php on line 44 and defined in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Hi2/api.php on line 123
[05-Apr-2016 06:21:19 Europe/Berlin] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: token in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Hi2/api.php on line 145
[05-Apr-2016 06:21:19 Europe/Berlin] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: error in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Hi2/api.php on line 149
```

It's saying token is an undefined variable, here is how I defined it in the method.

```
function stream($IdPhoto=0, $token) 

{

if ($IdPhoto==0) {

    ...

} else {

    $result = query("SELECT p.IdPhoto, p.device_token, p.IdUser FROM photos p JOIN login l ON (l.IdUser = p.IdUser) WHERE p.IdPhoto='%d' AND p.device_token='%d' ", $IdPhoto, $token);

}
```

What is the correct way to declare the `$token` variable?

Comment: "exits when this line is called": there is a reason. What does your web server's error log say? (`/var/log/apache2/error.log` on a typical system)

Comment: Use prepared statements ...

Comment: @Amadan I posted the logs above. What is the correct way to define the `$token` variable?

Comment: @zaggler thank you for your suggestion. Before delving in, I ask, what is the benefit to using the prepared statement in your opinion?

Comment: See [**here**](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp) about using statements with PDO... This explains it short and to the  point

Comment: Thank you for the link @zaggler. Will I be able to use a PDO statement on the fly or will it change the entire API? Right now, my current database connection is made in a different file.

Comment: Yes it will be fine. Your welcome!